# changed password for ubuntu user does not survive making a new AMI from instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am working on an Ubuntu AMI on Amazon EC2.

On a running instance, I changed the password of the ubuntu user to (let's say) 'foobar'.

(I know user passwords are not generally needed in EC2 because of ssh with public/private keys, but I'm setting up a web application that authenticates using unix usernames/passwords, so I need to make sure this works.)

I tried several ways of setting the password:

1. sudo passwd ubuntu
2. echo "ubuntu:foobar" | chpasswd
3. Setting it with chef's 'user' resource

In all cases, if I then make a new image from the running instance, and then
create an instance of that image, the ubuntu user will NOT have the password 'foobar'.

I can set the password and reboot a running instance and the correct password will
still be set, but after making a new image from the instance, no such luck.

This has worked for me before. Not sure why it's not working now. It's an EBS image.

**EDIT**: Adding the exact steps to reproduce the problem.

- Launch an instance of the public AMI `ami-1a05fa72`
- ssh to the instance and set ubuntu's password with `sudo passwd ubuntu`
- set the password to `foobar`
- create an image based on this instance
- launch an instance based on the image you just created
- Test whether `ubuntu`'s password is `foobar` by ssh'ing to the instance
  as `ubuntu` and typing `passwd`. It will first ask you for your
  current password. Type `foobar` and when this is rejected, you have
  reproduced the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Its' too late to answer, Still , Just for reference,

When launching an instance from an image,
AWS will disbale the root and main account for password authentication.

- in case ubuntu [user : root,ubuntu]
- in case ami  : [user : ec2-user]

It means , these account can not login through password authentication on a fresh launched ec2.

However, any other account, will be working. so let's suppose,
you create an instance from ubuntu, set password authentication yes in ssh
and setup password for ubuntu, along with this, you created another user for your self,
then ,you launch one instance  from the image of above configured ec2.

then password authentication **for ubuntu user will not work** , hwoever, **password authentication for another user will work.**

Answer (score 0):

Not to sound belittling, but this has happened to me before when I realized my AMI was created **before** I made the change to the password.

If that's not it, you might want to modify the sshd_config file as well. After changing the password with 'sudo passwd ubuntu', add the following line to your /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

This should enable password login. Reload your ssh with:

```
sudo reload ssh
```

and subsequently create a new AMI.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want password login via ssh. Setting the password is for authentication by a web app, not by ssh. And I am sure I set the password before creating the AMI, as I have now encountered this problem several times in a row.

Comment: Apparently cloud-init is at fault. This AMI uses cloud-init and at some point it must reset the password. I haven't figured out what it does yet, and I've come up with a totally insecure workaround involving a @reboot action in crontab. Luckily in this instance I don't care about security, and I want this particular password to be known to all users of the AMI, but the problem will remain for anyone else who encounters it and needs a secure solution.

Comment: Ah that's a very interesting workaround. You should post this to the AWS forums as well. Not having these basic system setting replicated seems counter-intuitive to how one would assume an AMI would behave.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, according to Hugh MacMullan on the Starcluster list, is:

"Have a look at /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg, particularly the 'default_user' section. Notice the 'lock_passwd: True'. You could change that to False ... OR better would be to create a different user (say, rlogin), which will NOT be locked by default on init, so you should be good to go."

I changed lock_passwd to False and my password change survived a reboot. No need for insecure crontab hacks.