How to set a default password for a user in a custom AMI?
I'm working on a project where I've created a custom environment that includes custom applications using the NVIDIA driver, CUDA, etc. Users need to sign in to this environment using RDP (xrdp) on an EC2 instance. I have this working on an instance based on the "Deep Learning Base OSS Nvidia Driver GPU AMI (Ubuntu 22.04)". My goal is to create a custom AMI from this instance so that users can easily start a new instance, log in via RDP, and use the environment.
In the base AMI, the "ubuntu" user doesn't have a password set. Currently, I can set the password manually by connecting to the instance via SSH and using sudo passwd ubuntu, but I'd like to avoid this step for end users who might not have SSH clients available. After creating the custom AMI and launching a new instance from it, the "ubuntu" user password I set on the original instance doesn't carry over to the new instances.
How can I set a default password for the "ubuntu" user in my custom AMI so that it persists across new instances? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

You should really use a tool like packer for baking new images. How are users going to be launching instances?

I'm new to AWS and wasn't aware of packer. My initial plan was for the user to have access to a limited AWS account, where they could launch instances by following a provided guide.
Will look into packer, thanks

If your use case is just to let users to connect to the EC2 instance you can ditribute a key pair that users will use when they create the EC2.
But if your needs is a password authentication for some reasons you can use AWS Image builder to:

Create a new image pipeline with the specified image
Create a new recipe with base image and the components (scripts or configuration changes) you want to apply.
Add a component with Linux as a platform and add a shell script to the install section.

script to add
#!/bin/bash
echo 'ubuntu:<your-password>' | chpasswd
echo 'disable_root: true' >> /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
echo 'ssh_pwauth: true' >> /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
echo 'chpasswd:' >> /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
echo '  expire: false' >> /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg


In the Image Recipe, add the component you just created.
run ths image pipeline


Thanks for the information. As explained in the answer to this question, the password for the default usernames on Ubuntu (like root or ubuntu) gets reset. So, I created a new user, and its credentials persist across new instances.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253847/changed-password-for-ubuntu-user-does-not-survive-making-a-new-ami-from-instance?rq=2

yes, but you still can control configurations at boot time using cloud init check : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/cloud-init.html and https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/22.2.2/topics/modules.html?highlight=password#set-passwords

For a quick and dirty fix, creating a new user worked for me. However, I'm now looking to disable ECC for NVIDIA GPUs to improve performance, but this setting also doesn't persist for new instances. I plan to apply both the password and GPU settings using the information you provided. Thanks!

For anyone facing the same problem, following is the solution that worked for me:
taken from here

When launching an instance from an image, AWS will disbale the root
and main account for password authentication.
in case ubuntu [user : root,ubuntu] in case ami : [user : ec2-user] It
means , these account can not login through password authentication on
a fresh launched ec2.
However, any other account, will be working. so let's suppose, you
create an instance from ubuntu, set password authentication yes in ssh
and setup password for ubuntu, along with this, you created another
user for your self, then ,you launch one instance from the image of
above configured ec2.
then password authentication for ubuntu user will not work , hwoever,
password authentication for another user will work.


NOTE ``
This may sound lame but i usually do this as follows,
during the initial creation of EC2 i set a user script which will automatically create a username and password for ubuntu user and then create then launch the ec2:
i put my script somthing like this :
#!/bin/bash
# Set the password for the 'ubuntu' user
echo "ubuntu:yourpassword" | chpasswd

# Allow the 'ubuntu' user to have password-based SSH access (if SSH is enabled)
sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/#PasswordAuthentication yes/PasswordAuthentication yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# Restart the SSH service to apply the changes (optional, if SSH is being used)
systemctl restart sshd


showing where to put user data script during the launch of EC2

and then you create the custome AMI out of this EC2.  This script will ensure that every time an instance is launched from this custome AMI, the "ubuntu" user will have the password you specified
please dont down vote me if i am wrong , as this is what i do ususally, comment i am wrong i will delete the answer , i am a begginner.
